# Google Identity Toolkit Android demo, Getting Network error

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I have been trying to set up sample Android app of Google Identity Toolkit demo ([gitkitdemo](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-android)).

Have followed the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart) and successfully set up the sample. **Login worked using my google accounts sometimes, but a lot of times mostly over mobile data(3G) I get following error:**

> https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=AIzaS3432QdokameMhwSzuQh_GTz423423U
>   07-26 14:14:13.300    5108-7306/pradeep.idtoolkit.demo E/GoogleIdpClient﹕ transient error encountered: NetworkError
>       java.io.IOException: NetworkError
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:130)
>               at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:120)
>               at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:84)
>               at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:71)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

My internet is working fine. Couldn't understand the reason for this. Is google identity toolkit production ready?

Please help if you have set this up before and can help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to give us some code and a more detailed error message. All we can do here is guess...

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue? the bug seems to only come when there is slow internet (3G), works on wifi and H network.

Answer (score 0):

did you properly configure your dev console set up and update the demo app settings? 
https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart
Please provide more details on your error.